# Notifications limited to a geographical area

Tags: ios, notifications, gps

It is something I only started to think about.
But is there a way to send notifications to users of a given iOS app, only if they happen to be in a certain geographical area?
Presuming I am the owner of the app and can modify the code to make that possibe (in case that is ever possibe)

More precisely the app has some kind of central service that sends notifications, but those notifications are only of interest to people in a given area. I do not want to bother the folks outside of that area with irrelevant notifications.

Comment: are you looking for push notification or local notification?

Comment: I guess I am looking for "push notifications". I modified my post, hoping to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

### For iOS 10 and later

If you want to send Local Notification with `UNNotificationRequest`, you can perform this as following:

1. Ask for `requestAlwaysAuthorization` and add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in `info.plist` file. Also add Background modes to Location.

   ```
   var locationManager:CLLocationManager
   ```

   inside `viewWillAppear` wirte this to ask for AlwaysAuthorization permission

   ```
   locationManager = CLLocationManager()
   locationManager.delegate = self
   locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
   ```
2. Then, use either `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` or `startUpdatingLocation`, to monitor location changes.
3. Implement CLLocationManagerDelegate `locationManager:didEnterRegion:` and show local notification when enters into specific location.

   ```
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion){
       //Show local notification when entered a desired location
       showLocalNotification("Entered \(region.identifier)")
   }

   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion){
       //Show local notification when exit from a desired location
        showLocalNotification("Exited \(region.identifier)")
   }
   ```

### For earlier versions

If you want to use `UILocalNotification`, you can add `CLRegion` in UILocalNotification object. iOS will automatically show a local notification when user enter/exits geographical area CLRegion.

```
let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
localNotification.alertTitle = "Hi there"
localNotification.alertBody = "you are here"

let region = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 4.254, longitude: 88.25), radius: CLLocationDistance(100), identifier: "")
region.notifyOnEntry = true
region.notifyOnExit = false
localNotification.region = region       

localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1) is a link from Apple, about *Getting the User’s Location*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using local notification then you can use the geofence. for more info check [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136165/core-location-geofencing-tutorial).

In geofence you can notify the on entry and on exit notifications. Based on the trigger you can set the notifications.

Comment: I am talking about notifications coming from a server.